# How to capture ipconfig's ipv4 through javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, html, servlets

In my office, some pc are connected through LAN. And they have allocated with a class A IP address. Now I have created a web application which is running on another server and accesable through LAN pcs. So, I have tried JavaScript code as well as some Java code to get the IP address of pc (which is visible through ipconfig command on that pc itself).

Below JavaScript code I have used to get IP address of LAN pcs:

```
< script >  
    var RTCPeerConnection = /*window.RTCPeerConnection ||*/ window.webkitRTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection;  
if (RTCPeerConnection)(function() {  
    var rtc = new RTCPeerConnection({  
        iceServers: []  
    });  
    if (1 || window.mozRTCPeerConnection) {  
        rtc.createDataChannel('', {  
            reliable: false  
        });  
    };  
    rtc.onicecandidate = function(evt) {  
        if (evt.candidate) grepSDP("a=" + evt.candidate.candidate);  
    };  
    rtc.createOffer(function(offerDesc) {  
        grepSDP(offerDesc.sdp);  
        rtc.setLocalDescription(offerDesc);  
    }, function(e) {  
        console.warn("offer failed", e);  
    });  
    var addrs = Object.create(null);  
    addrs["0.0.0.0"] = false;  
  
    function updateDisplay(newAddr) {  
        if (newAddr in addrs) return;  
        else addrs[newAddr] = true;  
        var displayAddrs = Object.keys(addrs).filter(function(k) {  
            return addrs[k];  
        });  
        document.getElementById('list').textContent = displayAddrs.join(" or perhaps ") || "n/a";  
    }  
  
    function grepSDP(sdp) {  
        var hosts = [];  
        sdp.split('\r\n').forEach(function(line) {  
            if (~line.indexOf("a=candidate")) {  
                var parts = line.split(' '),  
                    addr = parts[4],  
                    type = parts[7];  
                if (type === 'host') updateDisplay(addr);  
            } else if (~line.indexOf("c=")) {  
                var parts = line.split(' '),  
                    addr = parts[2];  
                updateDisplay(addr);  
            }  
        });  
    }  
})();  
else {  
    document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = "<code>ifconfig| grep inet | grep -v inet6 | cut -d\" \" -f2 | tail -n1</code>";  
    document.getElementById('list').nextSibling.textContent = "In Chrome and Firefox your IP should display automatically, by the power of WebRTCskull.";  
} < /script>
```

For localhost testing, it is giving perfect IPv4 IP address. But when I deploy my code in server, it's started giving something else.

In case of Java: this is my below code:

```
Enumeration<NetworkInterface> interfaces=NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
while(interfaces.hasMoreElements()){
    NetworkInterface current=interfaces.nextElement();
    Enumeration<InetAddress> addresses=current.getInetAddresses();
    while(addresses.hasMoreElements()){
        InetAddress current_addr=addresses.nextElement();
        if(current_addr instanceof Inet4Address){
            String hostAddr=current_addr.getHostAddress();
            String hostName=current_addr.getHostName();
        }
    }
}
```

This code also gives me IPv4 of the server in which my web application is deployed.
Please help me to get the IP address of the LAN pc which is visible through 'ipconfig' command on that PC.

Comment: For the Java, that will need to run on the client. This means running something like Web Start if you want to initiate the code *from the server*

Comment: Please provide any solution to my problem. Is it even possible to get solution of my problem? Please help I am total clueless. Everything works fine and gave correct result when running application on localhost. When it goes live, it started giving incorrect output. @g00se

Comment: You need to install Web Start on each client

Answer (score 0):

I think that Try with this -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/573225/(solved)-how-to-find-the-ip-address-im-using-(ethe

Comment: Thank you. I'll try this out. And let you know. @angelbeamud

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).